# powerShell: get "Select-Object -Property" boolean state to use in condition

Tags: powershell, shell, conditional-statements

I use some Powershell command to get if the property of an object is true or false:

```
Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object -Property OsPortableOperatingSystem

OsPortableOperatingSystem
-------------------------
                    False
```

Then I would like to check it and take a decision based off that:

```
if (OsPortableOperatingSystem)
     {dosomething}
```

How can I get the boolean result?

Comment: you need to save it to a $Var and then use `if ($Var.PropertyName)`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey how exactly do I do that?

Comment: it looks like `Martin Brandl` has pointed out how to assign values to variables & then use the resulting objects. glad to know that you got it working as needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

You should assign the result of the Get-ComputerInfo cmdlet to a variable to access it later:

```
$os = Get-ComputerInfo

if ($os.OsPortableOperatingSystem)
{
    # Do something...
}
```

If you don't need to access more information later, you can write your if statement like this:

```
if ((Get-ComputerInfo).OsPortableOperatingSystem)
{
    # Do something...
}
```